# Does Astro have theme composition and components shadowing?

Tags: gatsby, astrojs, shadowing, gatsby-theme

I am exploring `Astro` to see if it would be a good fit to migrate a large Gatsby theme over as I am not fully satisfied with the toolings offered and particularly the `Lighthouse` results.

I'm not seeing though any opportunity for [components shadowing](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/plugins-and-themes/shadowing/) and theme composition with [Gatsby themes](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/themes/).

Is there any `Astro` expert that maybe knows a workaround for this?

I have tried searching the official docs and even asking AI tools and deeply searching SO and GitHub for an answer but I couldn't find anything similar.

Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to use an existing Gatsby theme with Astro? That wouldn’t work I don’t think as Gatsby themes are designed as plugins that mutate your Gatsby config, and there is no Gatsby config in an Astro project.

The idea of a theme in Astro that does something similar (a plugin in `astro.config.mjs` that sets up parts of your project for you), does exist but is relatively new — the official [Starlight docs theme](https://starlight.astro.build/) works like this for example — but most things advertised as an Astro “theme” today are in fact example projects you can fork and then override components as you wish as the components will be directly in your project directory.

Comment: No I would actually port the websites in an Astro theme, but it seems like it's not supported. Thank you!